# Windows 8 system wide modal message dialog

Tags: windows, user-interface, winapi, kernel, driver

In windows 8/10, how do you create a "**system wide modal**" dialog/message/question like the one you get, for example, when windows prompts for permission when UAC is turned on?

Please, note the key point "system wide modal", creating an application modal dialog is not the issue, nor a problem.

(My) definition of a system wide modal message/dialog:
*A message that is displayed in such way that there is no way for a user to bypass it or ignore it. In the case of a message it contains an interactive element (button) that the user has to activate (click) in order to remove the message, and in the case of a question it has a predefined set of interactive elements the user can chose among (OK, Yes, No, cancel, Abort) to answer the question and close the question, and for a dialog it is a complete custom dialog, with custom content, where the developer decides what actions is needed to close the dialog. The key point is that there should be no way beside interacting with the message/question/dialog to get past it.*

Also, it doesn't matter if it requires a driver or interactions at the kernel level to accomplish this, so don't rule out solutions because they might seem complicated or difficult.

It is going to be extremely difficult and hard, but please try to refrain from expressing how rude, inappropriate and generally just how bad it is to create something that disturbs other applications, just accept the premise of "system wide modal" and that this is one of the very rare times where "system wide modal" is the correct solution. Please don't suggest alternative non system wide modal solutions.

Comment: Windows does this by snapshotting the current desktop then switching to another (the secure desktop) that's running under a system account.  Creating a new (empty) desktop then running your app there would be one approach.

Comment: Capture the desktop. Create a fullscreen window with no chrome that covers the desktop - this will hide the taskbar. Display your modal over that. There is no way - using just the mouse - to bypass this. If the user has access to a keyboard device that has key combinations that can task switch, then ensure that you are on a different desktop with no other tasks to switch to - as per Alex K's comment.

Comment: It's well documented how UAC works, what the secure desktop is. Why not do the same.